# Collision working, particle fx not so much C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll keep this brief and a bit short, but I currently have a particle system that seems to not be rendering even though my collision works.

I have trouble understanding other peoples work so I have not been able to find a solution I can understand.

Here is my code:

```
public float speed;
public Rigidbody rb;
public int health;
private float knockback;
private float knockup;
public ParticleSystem Eparticle; //*** variable for particle system ***

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody>();
    knockback = 100f;
    knockup = 250f;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy")
    {
        health = health - 20;
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.back * knockback);
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * knockup);
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        Instantiate(Eparticle);
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "endgoal")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with my instantiate(Eparticle) line?
Could someone please talk me through a solution?
Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke the `Instantiate` method at the position where you want the particle prefab to appear.
You could do something like this...

```
Instantiate(Eparticle,transform.position,transform.rotation);
```

Actually, you can also create (instantiate) a GameObject at runtime as follows...

```
GameObject obj= Instantiate(Eparticle,transform.position,transfrom.rotation) as GameObject;
```

This way, you have some sort of 'control' over the instantiated gameobject.
For instance, you can destroy the object after using it by calling the `Destroy()` method.
E.g.:

```
Destroy(obj,2f);//Destroys the created object after 2 seconds.
```

Of course, this is not a good way to go about it if you are going to be instantiating and destroying a lot of objects. You should read about *Object Pooling* for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly answered my question. You made it very clear!

Comment: You should accept the answer then. I'm glad I was able to help.